# Latex Fonts error

Tags: fonts, miktex, texmaker

I just downloaded MikTex and Texmaker, in order to write an article. But the compiler cannot compile mathematical formulas. When I put `\begin{equation} 'formula' \end{equation}`, I get the following error message:

```
35i,6n,27p,3241b,189s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file rtxr): Font rtxr at 657 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I get similar message when trying with $ or [...

What should I do ?
Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it could be a problem with symbols you use in tour equation, try to add the packages

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

all the best